# Orchestrator function 'XYZ' failed: The function 'XYZ' doesn't exist, is disabled, or is not an orchestrator function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions, orchestration

I'm trying to run Azure Orchestrations and I sunddenly I started getting the error from the statusQueryGetUri:

`Orchestrator function 'UploadDocumentOrchestrator' failed: The function 'UploadDocumentOrchestrator' doesn't exist, is disabled, or is not an orchestrator function.`

I've run this functions dozens of times today without any issue. VSCode doesn't flag any issues. I've tried restarting and that hasn't helped either.

This has happened once before. I got the error, troubleshot for like 3 hours, got frustrated, left, and came back to my computer an hour later and the problem was resolved without changing anything. I suspect the issue is related to caching somehow, but I'm not sure where to fix this.

There is a similar issue noted at:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/577

After I run `func start`, my "missing" orchestration appears in the launch screen indicating that it is valid as shown below.

I start the `UploadDocumentOrchestrator` with the HttpTrigger `StartUploadDocuments`. I see the trigger complete its execution `UploadDocumentOrchestrator` never starts in the logs.

```
    UploadDocumentOrchestrator: orchestrationTrigger

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2023-01-11T19:58:10.490Z] Executing 'StartUploadDocuments' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=f158ac3e-fa39-403c-9671-307ea54d5948)
[2023-01-11T19:58:10.599Z] Started orchestration with ID = '29b9ab7fcffe4f59bd47032ef21c19e8'.
[2023-01-11T19:58:10.620Z] Executed 'StartUploadDocuments' (Succeeded, Id=f158ac3e-fa39-403c-9671-307ea54d5948, Duration=154ms)
[2023-01-11T19:58:13.952Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '0000000000000000000000004906C298'.
```

Comment: As it mentioned in the Same GitHub Ticket, it is solved by clearing the Azure storage emulator data, check [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/577#issuecomment-563211574).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the name of the Durable hub i.e `"hubName": "DurableHub",` in `host.json` file of your Azure function application.

```
"durableTask": {
            "hubName": "DurableHub", // Change to your xyzhubname
            "storageProvider": {
                "connectionStringName": "ConnectionString" 
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. As it mentioned in the Same GitHub Ticket, it is solved by clearing the Azure storage emulator data, check [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/577#issuecomment-563211574).
2. It might be due to the Caching issue and also @*ConnorMcMahon* given another scenario in GitHub Issue #[1381](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/1381#issuecomment-642795324) of the same error - renaming the function caused the same issue for a few users:

> The function ‘XYZ’ doesn’t exist, is disabled, or is not an orchestrator function.

[image]